# Cannot use CCLOG in eclipse. the msg won't show up in my LogCat

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

Please, Help me. Thank you so much.
I am a very new and I am learning to develop android app by watching some tutorial video.
I am trying to use CCLOG in eclipse. All uppercase.
try to print the following msg.

```
CCLOG("Test String");
CCLOG("visibleSize:%.1f,%.1f",visibleSize.width,visibleSize.height);
CCLOG("origin:%.1f,%.1f",origin.x,origin.y);
```

They don't show up in eclipse LogCat, but when i use visual studio, they do show up in the output.

I have tried the following methods. but they didn't work.

1. put #define COCOS2D_DEBUG 1 at the really top (higher than any #include) in the cpp file
2. add -DCCOCOS2D_DEBUG=1 in Application.mk file like this:
   APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -DCC_ENABLE_CHIPMUNK_INTEGRATION=1 -std=c++11 -fsigned-char -DCCOCOS2D_DEBUG=1

It is just the HelloWorldScene of cocos2d-x

```
#define COCOS2D_DEBUG 1
#include "HelloWorldScene.h"

USING_NS_CC;

Scene* HelloWorld::createScene()
{
// 'scene' is an autorelease object
auto scene = Scene::create();

// 'layer' is an autorelease object
auto layer = HelloWorld::create();

// add layer as a child to scene
scene->addChild(layer);

// return the scene
return scene;
}

// on "init" you need to initialize your instance
bool HelloWorld::init()
{
//////////////////////////////
// 1. super init first
if ( !Layer::init() )
{
    return false;
}

Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
Vec2 origin = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin();

CCLOG("Test String");
CCLOG("visibleSize:%.1f,%.1f",visibleSize.width,visibleSize.height);
CCLOG("origin:%.1f,%.1f",origin.x,origin.y);



/////////////////////////////
// 2. add a menu item with "X" image, which is clicked to quit the program
//    you may modify it.

// add a "close" icon to exit the progress. it's an autorelease object
auto closeItem = MenuItemImage::create(
                                       "CloseNormal.png",
                                       "CloseSelected.png",
                                       CC_CALLBACK_1(HelloWorld::menuCloseCallback, this));

closeItem->setPosition(Vec2(origin.x + visibleSize.width - closeItem->getContentSize().width/2 ,
                            origin.y + closeItem->getContentSize().height/2));

// create menu, it's an autorelease object
auto menu = Menu::create(closeItem, NULL);
menu->setPosition(Vec2::ZERO);
this->addChild(menu, 1);

/////////////////////////////
// 3. add your codes below...

// add a label shows "Hello World"
// create and initialize a label

auto label = Label::createWithTTF("Hello World", "fonts/Marker Felt.ttf", 24);

// position the label on the center of the screen
label->setPosition(Vec2(origin.x + visibleSize.width/2,
                        origin.y + visibleSize.height - label->getContentSize().height));

// add the label as a child to this layer
this->addChild(label, 1);

// add "HelloWorld" splash screen"
auto sprite = Sprite::create("HelloWorld.png");

// position the sprite on the center of the screen
sprite->setPosition(Vec2(visibleSize.width/2 + origin.x, visibleSize.height/2 + origin.y));

// add the sprite as a child to this layer
this->addChild(sprite, 0);

return true;
}


void HelloWorld::menuCloseCallback(Ref* pSender)
{
Director::getInstance()->end();

#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_IOS)
    exit(0);
#endif
}
```

Thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0):

I did it in AppDelegate.h:

```
#ifndef  _APP_DELEGATE_H_
#define  _APP_DELEGATE_H_

#define COCOS2D_DEBUG 1
#include "cocos2d.h"

.. other stuff

#endif // _APP_DELEGATE_H_
```

and in Application.mk:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static

APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -DCC_ENABLE_CHIPMUNK_INTEGRATION=1 -std=c++11 -fsigned-char -DCCOCOS2D_DEBUG=1
APP_LDFLAGS := -latomic

APP_PLATFORM := android-11
APP_ABI=armeabi

#ifeq ($(NDK_DEBUG),1)
NDK_DEBUG:=1
APP_CPPFLAGS += -DCOCOS2D_DEBUG=1
APP_OPTIM := debug
#else
#  APP_CPPFLAGS += -DNDEBUG
#  APP_OPTIM := release
#endif
```

Try this it works for me in eclipse. If not you can also try adding:

```
android:debuggable="true"
```

in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Make sure you use debug log level. Also can you check if ordinary System.out.println or Log.d shows?

Comment: Hi. Yes System.out.ptintln shows. and I don't know why after i tried System.out.println,  CCLOG works suddenly. I did not change any setting or edit my codes. so weird. Thank you so much for the help. Thank you.